# Calculate average speed over x-distance

Tags: average

This is probably a very easy calculation to do, but I cant seem to solve it/confirm its 100% correct.

Lets say we have the following data to calculate the average speed with:

**- distance from A to B** = 1243 meters
**- default speed to move an object from A to B** = 2030 meters per second

The first 118 meters are at a speed of **1450** meters per second.
After those 118 meters its back to its default value of **2030**.

Im unsure if the result of my calculation is correct.
This was my calculation:

```
vavg = 1243 / ((118/1450) + ((1243-118)/2030))

     = 1243 / (.08 + .55)

     = 1973 m/s.
```

Comment: Be careful of rounding off errror. Pls see my answer.

Comment: I noticed, tyvm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Average speed is total distance divided by total time.

Time taken for first leg = $\frac{118} {1450} $ seconds.

Time taken for second leg = $\frac{1243-118} {2030} $ seconds.

So average speed = $\frac{1243} {\frac{118} {1450} +\frac{1243-118} {2030}} \approx 1956 ms^{-1}   $